# captureStillImageAsynchronously at specific time not working

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, avcapturesession

I am writing an application that takes an images every 0.1 seconds after the user presses a button.  However I'm having trouble getting a consistent 0.1 second delay between images.

Is this due to the fact that `captureStillImageAsynchronously` is asynchronous closure?  Would switching to `capturePhoto` from `AVCapturePhotoOutput` fix this issue?  Here is a summary of my code.

```
var stillImageOutput : AVCaptureStillImageOutput?

// Button action.
 @IBAction func takeImage(_ sender: UIButton) {      
    //take 1 image every 0.1 seconds scheduled using a timer
    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1,
                        target: self,
                        selector: #selector(calldidPressTakePhoto),
                        userInfo: nil,
                        repeats: true)
}

// Take image
    func didPressTakePhoto(){

        if let videoConnection = stillImageOutput?.connection(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo){

            videoConnection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait

            //Capture image.  everything in this closure is ASYNCHRONOUS?
            stillImageOutput?.captureStillImageAsynchronously(from: videoConnection, completionHandler: {
                (sampleBuffer, error) in

                //Do something with the result image...

            })
        }
    }
```

Comment: My guess would be the asynchronous issue like you suggested. By executing asynchronously, you are basically saying you don't care when the code gets executed, but just to do it in the background. So you'll never get consistently even time intervals.

Comment: As for your second question, `capturePhoto` calls a delegate method, so unfortunately that wouldn't be consistent with timing either.

Answer (score 0):

My best bet is that while .captureStillImageAsynchronously Is asynchronous it still accesses a shared resource and thus quite likely will have an internal mutex that prevents you from calling it so quickly that it would overlap in execution. I think that your camera has problems keeping up with your fire rate of 0.1s.